# Regular Expression - вывод строки ПОЛНОСТЬЮ, а не только искомый фрагмент

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, текст

**Good afternoon, dear friends!
Подскажите, пожалуйста...**

Есть определённая переменная `а` в которой куча строк с данными.

При помощи: `re.findall  [\w\.+]+-[A-Za-z-]+`   - вывожу найденные куски строк.

Каким образом, можно вывести строки целиком, содержащую данный фрагмент ( `[\w\.+]+-[A-Za-z-]+`) ???

________Пример кода:_______________________________________________________

```
import re

a = """A-1 Cafe Restaurant","Mon, Wed-Sun 11 am - 10 pm"
"Nick's Lighthouse","Mon-Sun 11 am - 10:30 pm"
"Paragon Restaurant & Bar","Mon-Fri 11:30 am - 10 pm  / Sat 5:30 pm - 10 pm"""

text_which_we_fond = r"[\w\.+]+-[A-Za-z-]+"  # шаблон поиска
all_results = re.findall(text_which_we_fond, a)

for i in all_results:
    print (i)
```

____________it will:_____________________________________________________________

```
Wed-Sun
Mon-Sun
Mon-Fri
```

_________________А нужно, чтобы программа выводила:____________________________
Строки целиком...

```
"A-1 Cafe Restaurant","Mon, Wed-Sun 11 am - 10 pm"
"Nick's Lighthouse","Mon-Sun 11 am - 10:30 pm"
"Paragon Restaurant & Bar","Mon-Fri 11:30 am - 10 pm  / Sat 5:30 pm - 10 pm
```

***Каким образом это сделать?!***

Comment: `for string in a: if re.match(r"[\w\.+]+-[A-Za-z-]+", string): print(string)`?

Comment: `text_which_we_fond = r"[\w.+]+-[A-Za-z-]+"  # шаблон поиска`, `reg = re.compile(text_which_we_fond)`, `all_results = list(filter(reg.search, a.splitlines()))`, [демо](https://ideone.com/nZOUyr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Python гораздо удобнее разбить текст на строки с помощью `str.splitlines()` (кстати, этот метод справляется с любыми последовательностями переноса строки), а затем отфильтровать только те строки, в которых есть совпадение с помощью предварительно откомпилированного регулярного выражения и метода `re.search`:

```
text_which_we_fond = r"[\w.+]+-[A-Za-z-]+" # шаблон поиска
reg = re.compile(text_which_we_fond)       # откомпилированное регулярное выражение
all_results = list(filter(reg.search, a.splitlines()))
```

См. [демо онлайн](https://ideone.com/nZOUyr). Результат:

```
"A-1 Cafe Restaurant","Mon, Wed-Sun 11 am - 10 pm"
"Nick's Lighthouse","Mon-Sun 11 am - 10:30 pm"
"Paragon Restaurant & Bar","Mon-Fri 11:30 am - 10 pm  / Sat 5:30 pm - 10 pm"
```

Answer (score 3):

Просто смени регулярку: https://ideone.com/vmBEAe

```
import re

a = """A-1 Cafe Restaurant","Mon, Wed-Sun 11 am - 10 pm"
"Nick's Lighthouse","Mon-Sun 11 am - 10:30 pm"
"Paragon Restaurant & Bar","Mon-Fri 11:30 am - 10 pm  / Sat 5:30 pm - 10 pm"""

text_which_we_fond = r"[^\r\n]*[\w\.+]+-[A-Za-z-]+[^\r\n]*"  # шаблон поиска
all_results = re.findall(text_which_we_fond, a)

for i in all_results:
    print (i)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = """A-1 Cafe Restaurant","Mon, Wed-Sun 11 am - 10 pm"
А нужно, чтобы программа выводила:____________________________ Строки целиком...
"Nick's Lighthouse","Mon-Sun 11 am - 10:30 pm"
"Paragon Restaurant & Bar","Mon-Fri 11:30 am - 10 pm  / Sat 5:30 pm - 10 pm"""

text_which_we_fond = r"[\w\.+]+-[A-Za-z-]+"

all_results = [ line for line in  a.split('\n') if re.findall(text_which_we_fond, line)]

for i in all_results:
    print (i)


A-1 Cafe Restaurant","Mon, Wed-Sun 11 am - 10 pm"
"Nick's Lighthouse","Mon-Sun 11 am - 10:30 pm"
"Paragon Restaurant & Bar","Mon-Fri 11:30 am - 10 pm  / Sat 5:30 pm - 10 pm
```